# Chef Ruby hash.merge VS hash[new_key]

Tags: ruby, hash, chef-infra

I ran into an odd issue when trying to modify a chef recipe. I have an attribute that contains a large hash of hashes. For each of those sub-hashes, I wanted to add a new key/value to a 'tags' hash within. In my recipe, I create a 'tags' local variable for each of those large hashes and assign the tags hash to that local variable.

I wanted to add a modification to the tags hash, but the modification had to be done at compile time since the value was dependent on a value stored in an input json. My first attempt was to do this:

```
tags = node['attribute']['tags']
tags['new_key'] = json_value
```

However, this resulted in a spec error that indicated I should use node.default, or the equivalent attribute assignment function. So I tried that:

```
tags = node['attribute']['tags']
node.normal['attribute']['tags']['new_key'] = json_value
```

While I did not have a spec error, the new key/value was not sticking.

---

At this point I reached my "throw stuff at a wall" phase and used the hash.merge function, which I used to think was functionally identical to hash['new_key'] for a single key/value pair addition:

```
tags = node['attribute']['tags']
tags.merge({ 'new_key' => 'json_value' })
```

This ultimately worked, but I do not understand why. What functional difference is there between the two methods that causes one to be seen as a modification of the original chef attribute, but not the other?

Comment: I have never used Chef, but keep in mind that `[]` is a method that can be overridden, so maybe whatever Chef uses isn't really a Hash but something that uses a similar interface.

Comment: That sounds likely. Am I right in assuming my initial understanding works for standard Ruby?

Comment: `node` is not a `Hash`. `node` is a `Chef::Node` the `[]` method gives you access to a `Chef::Attribute` also not a `Hash` but closer it is a `Mash` which is `Chef`s subclass of `Hash`. Why the first version did not work I cannot explain as `[]=(arg)` is a writer. Additionally why `merge` did work does not make sense either since it is not destructive (meaning it creates a copy and modifies the copy leaving the original intact) in essence `[]=` is actually similar to `merge!`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you can't use `node['foo']` like that. That accesses the merged view of all attribute levels. If you then want to set things, it wouldn't know where to put them. So you need to lead off by tell it where to put the data:

```
tags = node.normal['attribute']['tags']
tags['new_key'] = json_value
```

Or just:

```
node.normal['attribute']['tags']['new_key'] = json_value
```

Beware of setting things at the `normal` level though, it is not reset at the start of each run which is probably what you want here, but it does mean that even if you remove the recipe code doing the set, the value will still be in place on any node that already ran it. If you want to actually remove things, you have to do it explicitly.